# php jquery jcrop and imagejpeg

Tags: php, jquery, jcrop

That's my first approach with GD stuff.
I'm trying to implement resize and crop using jcrop jquery plugin.
I still can't figure out how to save the image I've cropped. On the jcrop site there's not much about it. here's my code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = 'demo_files/flowers.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
            $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

     header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

     imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
```

What do I do with **imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality)** in order to actually write the image file and save its path in my db?

Thanks in advance.

Mauro

Comment: Can you install ImageMagick on your server? It's a ton easier, in my opinion, than wrestling with GD. I don't use the ImageMagick PHP extension, but just call the commands via `exec()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save the file instead of outputting it, do these two things:

- Remove the line `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`
- Change the next line after that to `imagejpeg($dst_r, 'path/to/output.jpg', $jpeg_quality);`

See the docs for the `imagejpeg()` function at [php.net/imagejpeg](http://php.net/imagejpeg)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. One question: is 'path/to/output.jpg' the path where the cropped image will be saved?

Comment: Indeed. The documentation says: "The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly."